# Is binary.Read slow?

Tags: go

I'm rewriting an old small C project into Go (to learn Go).

The project basically reads some binary data from a file, does some filtering on said data, then prints it into stdout.

The main part of the code looks like this (omitting error handling):

```
type netFlowRow struct {
    Timestamp uint32
    Srcip     [4]byte
    Dstip     [4]byte
    Proto     uint16
    Srcport   uint16
    Dstport   uint16
    Pkt       uint32
    Size      uint64
}

func main() {
    // ...
    file, _ := os.Open(path)
    for j := 0; j < infoRow.Count; j++ {
        netRow := netFlowRow{}
        binary.Read(file, binary.BigEndian, &netRow)

        // ...
        fmt.Printf("%v", netRow)
    }
}
```

After doing a naive rewrite go version ran 10 times slower than the C version (~40s vs 2-3s). I did profiling with pprof and it showed me this:

```
(pprof) top10
39.96s of 40.39s total (98.94%)
Dropped 71 nodes (cum <= 0.20s)
Showing top 10 nodes out of 11 (cum >= 39.87s)
      flat  flat%   sum%        cum   cum%
    39.87s 98.71% 98.71%     39.87s 98.71%  syscall.Syscall
     0.09s  0.22% 98.94%     40.03s 99.11%  encoding/binary.Read
         0     0% 98.94%     39.87s 98.71%  io.ReadAtLeast
         0     0% 98.94%     39.87s 98.71%  io.ReadFull
         0     0% 98.94%     40.03s 99.11%  main.main
         0     0% 98.94%     39.87s 98.71%  os.(*File).Read
         0     0% 98.94%     39.87s 98.71%  os.(*File).read
         0     0% 98.94%     40.21s 99.55%  runtime.goexit
         0     0% 98.94%     40.03s 99.11%  runtime.main
         0     0% 98.94%     39.87s 98.71%  syscall.Read
```

Am I reading this right? Is syscall.Syscall basically the main time consumer? Is it where the reading from file is going on?

Upd.
I used bufio.Reader and got this profile:

```
(pprof) top10
34.16s of 36s total (94.89%)
Dropped 99 nodes (cum <= 0.18s)
Showing top 10 nodes out of 33 (cum >= 0.56s)
      flat  flat%   sum%        cum   cum%
    31.99s 88.86% 88.86%        32s 88.89%  syscall.Syscall
     0.43s  1.19% 90.06%      0.64s  1.78%  runtime.mallocgc
     0.39s  1.08% 91.14%      1.06s  2.94%  encoding/binary.(*decoder).value
     0.28s  0.78% 91.92%      0.99s  2.75%  reflect.(*structType).Field
     0.28s  0.78% 92.69%      0.28s  0.78%  runtime.duffcopy
     0.24s  0.67% 93.36%      1.64s  4.56%  encoding/binary.sizeof
     0.22s  0.61% 93.97%     34.51s 95.86%  encoding/binary.Read
     0.22s  0.61% 94.58%      0.22s  0.61%  runtime.mach_semaphore_signal
     0.07s  0.19% 94.78%      1.28s  3.56%  reflect.(*rtype).Field
     0.04s  0.11% 94.89%      0.56s  1.56%  runtime.newobject
```

Comment: And yeah, the file is about 1GB

Comment: There is going to be overhead to `binary.Read`, as it uses [reflection](https://godoc.org/reflect). I would suggest benchmarking both: (a) using `bufio.Reader` instead of reading directly from the file, and (b) using `binary.BigEndian.*` methods to read the fields directly instead of `binary.Read` on the entire struct.

Comment: Did your C program use a FILE* and e.g. calling fread() ? If so you should wrap the file in go in a bufio.Reader so you do buffered reads like the C program

Comment: I've updated the question with profile data with `bufio.Reader`

Comment: The C program used FILE*, yes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`binary.Read` will be slower, due to the fact that it uses [reflection](https://godoc.org/reflect). I would suggest bench-marking using `bufio.Reader` and manually invoking the `binary.BigEndian` methods to read your struct:

```
type netFlowRow struct {
    Timestamp uint32   // 0
    Srcip     [4]byte  // 4
    Dstip     [4]byte  // 8
    Proto     uint16   // 12
    Srcport   uint16   // 14
    Dstport   uint16   // 16
    Pkt       uint32   // 18
    Size      uint64   // 22
}

func main() {
    // ...
    file, _ := os.Open(path)
    r := bufio.NewReader(file)
    for j := 0; j < infoRow.Count; j++ {
        var buff [4 + 4 + 4 + 2 + 2 + 2 + 4 + 8]byte
        if _, err := io.ReadFull(r, buff[:]); err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
        netRow := netFlowRow{
            Timestamp: binary.BigEndian.Uint32(buff[:4]),
            // Srcip
            // Dstip
            Proto: binary.BigEndian.Uint16(buff[12:14]),
            Srcport: binary.BigEndian.Uint16(buff[14:16]),
            Dstport: binary.BigEndian.Uint16(buff[16:18]),
            Pkt: binary.BigEndian.Uint32(buff[18:22]),
            Size: binary.BigEndian.Uint64(buff[22:30]),
        }
        copy(netRow.Srcip[:], buff[4:8])
        copy(netRow.Dstip[:], buff[8:12])

        // ...
        fmt.Printf("%v", netRow)
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is much faster (from 40s to 4s)!
But mostly I just don't understand the output of profiler. Why is `Syscall` the slowest function??

Comment: @F0RR: syscall wasn't the slowest function, it's the function that was in process the most often during profiling. You weren't using buffered io and were making too many small read calls on the file.

Comment: @JimB ok, got that. Thanks :)